# Thevenin's theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

So I watched a couple videos on Youtube about Thevenin's theorem and I found 2 ways to do this circuit,but I get two different answers and I'm confused now.(for finding \$V_{th}\$)
First method is

\$V_{th} = (V_s/R_1+R_2)R_2\$ and i get 24 V

The second method is using KCL 
so, \$I_1-I_2+I_3=0\$ and I get \$V_{th}\$ = 30V

are both ways right and I'm just calculating wrong or I can't use method 1 for this circuit. Can someone explain please.

[image: picture of a hand-drawn circuit]

Comment: They should definitely give you the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use Thévenin's and Norton's theorem in each of the elements instead. Start from your circuit, and apply Norton to the 32V supply and the 4 Ohms resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgtoml.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then add the two current supplies and find the parallel equivalent of the 4 and 12 Ohms resistors (which is 3 Ohms).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiJpD3.png)</sup>

Now all you have to do is apply Thévenin again and you pretty much have your answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ToET.png)</sup>